# Getting a 'was not declared in this scope' error

Tags: c++

```
void new_doubles(double a, double b, double c)
{
double d=max(abs(a), abs(b), abs(c));
cout<<d;
}
```

produces this compile time error :

```
In file included from /usr/local/gcc4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
from /usr/local/gcc4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/string:40,
from /usr/local/gcc4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/stdexcept:39,
from /usr/local/gcc4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/array:38,
from std_lib_facilities_4.h:27,
from hw4pr4.cpp:1: /usr/local/gcc4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘const _Tp&                                           std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _Tp = double; _Compare = double]’:
 hw4pr4.cpp:35:36: required from here
/usr/local/gcc4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:264:26: error: ‘__comp’ cannot be used as    a function
if (__comp(__a, __b))
```

I dont understand why this error is being produced can anyone help explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your title says "was not declared in this scope" (and the lack of quotation marks around the message makes your title very hard to read). That message doesn't appear in the body of your question. Also, please update your question to show a complete code sample. Your actual code must have one or more `#include` directives; we need to see them.

Answer (score 5):

The only overload of `std::max` with three arguments is used to give the larger of the first two, interpreting the third as a comparison function to use instead of `<` to compare the values. It doesn't give the largest of three values.

To get the largest of three values, use the overload that takes an initialiser list:

```
double d=max({abs(a), abs(b), abs(c)});
             ^                      ^
```

Or, if you're stuck in a pre-C++11 world, call the overload for two values twice:

```
double d=max(abs(a), max(abs(b), abs(c)));
                     ^^^^              ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Max does not take three arguments in the way you think it does.

```
double d=max(max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs(c));
```

Comment: Thanks tried:
    double d=max(abs(a), abs(b));
    d= max(d,abs(c));

Answer (score 0):

@GWW is correct but if you are using a C++ 11 compiler, there is a new variadic variation - you just need to supply an initializer list with multiple args instead of multiple args:

```
void new_doubles(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double d = max( { abs(a), abs(b), abs(c) } );
    cout << d;
}
```